# Trouble getting parameters from Android to PHP file for SQL query

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, mysqli

I have tried searching about this but could not find any useful answers. 
I am attempting to run a query on my database (hosted on a web server) from my Android emulator using eclipse. I can confirm that the correct result of the query is found when I use a constant in the PHP script but when I attempt to pass parameters through it, there is no result. Also, the mysqli does work but I have edited it for this post.

The following is the PHP: 
As stated earlier when :name was replaced with a specified string the correct result was returned.

```html
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","mylogin","mypass","mydb");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
//$username = $_GET['username'];
//$password = $_GET['password'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT firstname FROM users WHERE email =  ':name'");
 $result_params = array(
  ':name' => $_POST['MyName']
);  
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$data = $row[0];
if($data){
echo $data;
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Here is the Java as well

```html
 public void postData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(LOGIN_URL);
    
           MyName = MainActivity.getEmail();
            
           try {
               // Building Parameters
            MyName = MainActivity.getEmail();
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
         params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("MyName", MyName));

         httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
         
        // Execute HTTP Post Request
         ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
       String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
       //response from PHP application 
       String nameString = response;
       
         welcomename.setText("Welcome " + nameString);
           } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
         
         } catch (IOException e) {
         
         }
}
```

So to summarise, my question is :What do I need to add to the code to get the parameter 'MyName' from the Java code being posted into the SQL query in the PHP code. I have checked MyName is containing the correct result so the problem I think is on the PHP side.

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Comment: I would make the request from Fiddler or something like that, and then you'll know if the problem is with the client or the server.

Comment: I think the problem is with the server. Other scripts I have tested do work, it's just the problem of posting the data into the PHP script I have a problem with.

Comment: OK, can't help you then as I don't know PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the parameter like this.

```
$stmt=$con->prepare('SELECT firstname FROM users WHERE email = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['MyName'] );
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```